# Converting types from string to float+sorting a vector

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I'm trying to sort my *vectorlist* in descending order, according to one of its value (let's say it's average). 
i.e. My vector looks like that:

```
Name   score  Average
Bob    16     10.3
Alan   10     8.6
...
```

The problem is that all of the variables are string type and I can't sort it right, because when it gets above 10, program doesn't sort correct. So I've been trying to change my *list[i].average* and *list[j].average* type to float, to compare it (bubble sort), but when I do, program just crashes (I'm pretty sure it's because of incorrect conversion)... Here's an example of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;

class Person
{
    string name;
    string score;
    string average;
    vector<Person> temp;
public:
    void sort_vector(vector<Person> list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; i < list.size(); j++)
            {
                double iTemp = stod(list[i].average);
                double jTemp = stod(list[j].average);

                if (iTemp < jTemp)
                {
                    temp.push_back(list[i]);
                    list[i] = list[j];
                    list[j] = temp.back();

                    temp.clear();
                    iTemp = 0;
                    jTemp = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << list[i].average << endl;    //check
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<Person> list;  //let's say it's already full
    Person player;
    player.sort_vector(list);

    return 0;
}
```

Question: how do I convert average correctly, so I could sort my list?
Thanks!

Comment: 1) float or double? 2) you don't need your temp vector. 3) use stl for sort. The example here should cover what you need: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Comment: Why not use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with a suitable compare function?

Comment: Also, I recommend you use a debugger. You would then be able to see whether or not your problem is in the string to double conversion or not.

Comment: my mistake i meant stof

Comment: Where is `average` set at? I think we need more code. If `average` isn't being set, that's your problem. `std::stod()` throws an exception if it cannot convert the value to a decimal. I'm guessing an empty string would cause that.

Comment: average set inside a file, with all the other information. I copied everything from a file to vector using getline, so now vector has string type values that i need to compare. I just didn't want to trouble you with the ifstream/copyToVector part

Comment: `for (int j = i + 1; i < list.size(); j++)` Note that the condition in the middle checks `i`, not `j`. Eventually, `j` would go out of bounds for `list[j]` access.

Comment: Gotcha - I think it may be useful to add. At the very least, figure out how to debug in whatever IDE you are using, and see if you can catch an error being thrown. [See this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for help if you don't know how. :)

Comment: @tendor, you can convert a string to other primitive types using `stringstream()`